Question re: layout and grounding of a PCB with SPI-controlled H-bridges and load switches
My question is regarding the layout, and in particular the grounding, of a PCB that has a microcontroller that controls various H-bridge drivers (that will be PWM’d) and load switches via SPI. The largest of them switch 10~15 A of current, and they all switch 12 V.
All the motor drivers and load switch ICs have a single ground connection (there is not a separate signal ground and power ground.) From what I understand, there needs to be a good return path for the power currents, and a good return path for the I/O signals, especially the SPI.
The H-bridge drivers are from the TI DRV824x series, and their datasheets show an example layout with a 4-layer board:

On each side of the IC, the topmost 5 pins are logic (including SPI), and the remainder are the motor supply, ground and output pins. This example board has power/ground fed from the top (as noted by the arrows, along with the tabs at the top of the second and third layers.) I’m wondering why it’s like that, as opposed to power/ground being fed from the bottom so that the high currents can avoid the logic area up top?
The load switches are from the Infineon BTS71xxx series, and their datasheets show a schematic of a typical application:

In particular, there is Rvdd (470 Ω) for “device logic protection”, Rgnd (47 Ω) for “ground voltage spike filtering for improved robustness.” I’m trying to understand why this is necessary, if it’s a good idea, and whether other devices on this board should have these resistors as well?
Based on my research thus far, this is what I’m planning for the design:

It will be a 4 layer board with one or preferably two ground planes. Ground plane(s) because of the need of low-inductance return paths for the power and SPI.
There will be no splitting of the ground plane(s), however the board will be partitioned into distinct digital, analog, and high power areas.

My main questions are:

Is my stated approach on the right track?
If the board will be partitioned into distinct digital, analog, and high power areas, where should power (and more importantly) ground be fed to the board relative to these areas?
From the DRV824x example board, the traces coming out of the logic pins are quite long and run beside the bulk capacitor. Is this likely to cause issues? In particular with the SPI, where from what I understand you want to minimize stub lengths, and this layout would have the actual bus running above the capacitor and the traces in the example would be the stubs. Note that the bus doesn’t need to run super fast (the slowest devices are 5 MHz and I could probably get away with running it slower if necessary) and the example schematics for many of the devices have series resistors on the SPI lines

